# How to make a div scroll automatically in react (hooks)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently making a chat application and having trouble making the div scroll to the bottom when a new chat message is added, I used the css overflow-y:auto to make it be able to scroll but can't figure out how to make it always scroll to the bottom when a new chat is loaded.

Here is my app.js file:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState ,useRef} from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';


let socket;
const CONNECTION_PORT = "localhost:3002/";

function App() {
  //before login
  const [logged, setLogged] = useState(false);
  const [name,setName] = useState("");
  const [room,setRoom] = useState("");

  //after login
  const [message,setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messageList,setMessageList] = useState([]);

  const ref = useRef();



  useEffect(()=>{
    socket = io(CONNECTION_PORT,{transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
    
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on('recieve_message', (data)=>{
        setMessageList([...messageList,data])
    })
  });

//   useEffect(()=>{
//  const objDiv = document.getElementById('scroll');
//     objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    
//   },[message])


  function connectRoom(){
    socket.emit('join', room)
    setLogged(true);
  }

  function sendMessage(e){
    
    let messageContent = {
      room:room,
      content:{
        author:name,
        message:message
      }
    }
    socket.emit('send_message',messageContent)
    setMessageList([...messageList,messageContent.content])
    setMessage("");

    

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        {!logged?(
        <div className="background">  
          <div className="box">
            <span className="text-center">login</span>
          <div className="input-container">
            <input type="text" required="" onChange={e=> setName(e.target.value)}/>
            <label>Full Name</label>        
          </div>
          <div className="input-container">     
            <input type="text" required="" onChange={ e=> setRoom(e.target.value)}/>
            <label>Room</label>
          </div>
            <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={connectRoom}>submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        ):(
            <>

                <div className="chatContainer">

                    <div className="messages" id="scroll">
                        {messageList.map((val,key)=>{
                            return (

                            <div className="messageContainer" id={val.author == name ? "You" : "Other"}>

                                <div className="messageIndividual">
                                    {val.message}
                                </div>
                                <h1> {val.author}</h1>
                            </div>
                            );
                        })} 
                    </div>

                <div className="messageInputs">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Here" onChange={ e=> setMessage(e.target.value)}/>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}> Send</button>
                </div>
                
                </div>
                
                
            </>
        
          )}


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is my css file:

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.App{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2a2730;
}

.background{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.text-center{
    color:#fff; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: -50px 0 80px 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.box{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:70px 100px;
}
.input-container{
    position:relative;
  margin-bottom:25px;

}
.input-container label{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#fff; 
    pointer-event:none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.input-container input{ 
  border:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #555;  
  background:transparent;
  width:100%;
  padding:8px 0 5px 0;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#fff;
}
.input-container input:focus{ 
 border:none;   
 outline:none;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e74c3c;   
}
.btn{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#e74c3c;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-top:50px;
    border-radius:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}
/*.btn:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}*/
.input-container input:focus ~ label,
.input-container input:valid ~ label{
    top:-12px;
    font-size:12px;
    
}


.chatContainer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 5px solid #0091ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .chatContainer .messages {
    flex: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* flex-direction: column-reverse; */
    
  }
  
  .chatContainer .messageInputs {
    flex: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  
  }
  
  .chatContainer .messageInputs input{
    flex: 80%;
    height: calc(100% -5px);
    border: none;
    border-top: 5px solid #0091ff;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .chatContainer .messageInputs button{
    flex: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0091ff;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .messageContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .messageContainer h1{
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 17px;
    
  }
  
  #You{
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  
  #Other {
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  
  #You .messageIndividual {
    background-color: #5ff064;
    color: black;
  }
  .messageIndividual {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: #0091ff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    padding: 4px;
    
  
  }
```

here is what the chat application looks like:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add working snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a span with ref bellow messages list that will be scroll into it when new messages are received.

**Try this example :**

**useEffect :**

```
  useEffect(() => {
     scrollSpan.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [messageList]);
```

**useRef :**

```
 const scrollSpan= useRef();
```

**JSX :**

```
  <div className="messages" id="scroll">
                    {messageList.map((val,key)=>{
                        return (
                        <div className="messageContainer" id={val.author == name ? 
                        "You" : "Other"}>

                            <div className="messageIndividual">
                                {val.message}
                            </div>
                            <h1> {val.author}</h1>
                        </div>
                        );
                    })} 
          <span ref={scrollSpan}></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: I did a simple example from your code you can check out this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n9a5oo?file=src/App.js , it works fine the problem is fixed by separate the scroll effect from the socket.on() action, you can make another useEffect with messageList as param.
Also, I did update my answer (useEffect section) hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

On your 'messageContainer' div, create a reference using the 'useRef' React hook.

```
...
const container = useRef();
...
..
return (
    ...
    <div class="messageContainer" ref={ container }>...</div>
);
```

and use one more useEffect as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    container.current.scrollTop = chatBoxRef.current.scrollHeight;
}, [messageList]);
```

Some improvements(!important) to your code, which could prevent memory leaks in your app:

-so you're doing this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on('recieve_message', (data)=>{
        setMessageList([...messageList,data])
    })
  });
```

This causes a new 'receive message' event to get registered to the socket every time your component re-renders. You don't want that. You want this event to get registered just once. So do as follows:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on('recieve_message', (data)=>{
        setMessageList(prevMessageList => [...prevMessageList, data]);
    })
  }, []);
```

Note the change in setMessageList.(Look up why I did that, it is related to closures since this useEffect now runs only on the first render).